# Spacy Doc not parsing and processing text

Tags: python, heroku, flask, nlp, spacy

I'm creating a Flask endpoint so I can do some text processing, and in order to get the spacy english model to load I'm downloading the model file through my Pipfile when I push to Heroku.  Whereas before when working locally I was loading the model with:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(text)
```

Now I download the `en_core_web_sm` during the build on heroku (or even when running `heroku local web` and do:

```
import en_core_web_sm

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
doc = nlp(text)
```

Weirdly the spacy Doc object is still created, the model is loaded, but...nothing happens.  It doesn't tokenize, it doesn't run the entity extractor, nada.  What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't do nothing? What is the output of print(doc) or for token in doc: print token.pos_ ?